# Recover NTFS deleted folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, directory

My client accidently deleted a folder under a Server 2008 shared folder which permanently deleted it.

Does Windows offer some sort of restore for deleted files/folders? Or is there a good reliable program available?

Unfortunately the client's backup failed last night.

Comment: Do you have Volume Shadow Copy running on this volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Volume Shadow Copy is running, open explorer and navigate to the parent folder for the deleted item
- Right click & select properties
- Select the previous versions tab
- dbl click on the version just prior to the deletion
- when the explorer window opens with the old data, copy the deleted folder to the original explorer window

Comment: I wish VSS was enabled!

Comment: hmmm, no backup, no shadow copy.  No nets left I'm afraid